# Reading a Single char from a String?

Tags: c

I am doing an exercise in C which takes a string like (a8$£de95") from the user and searches for letters (the smallest and largest) and then types the smallest and the largest letter and whatever letters in-between in this example it should show "abcde"  and after this it types 2 letters which are already in order in which case they are "de".
Now I wrote a basic program to help get an understanding of characters as I have not solved any char/string exercise before (all the previous exercises where with numbers only). I wrote

```
char y;
printf("enter your string:- ");
scanf("%s",&y);
printf("%c",&y[2]);
return 0;
```

but it shows me nothing so  my question is, how do I read 1 character from a string and how does the computer know what is the smallest and largest letter and how do I make it type the letters in between?
thanks

Comment: First you need some place to store the string. And a variable that holds a singe character won't do.

Comment: `char y` that is memory for one char - perhaps an array?

Comment: Then read the manual pages for `scanf` and `printf`

Comment: The `%s` format needs at least 2 characters to point at, one for the character and one for the null terminator byte.  Use `" %c"` to read a single character (the space is _not_ an accident — it simulates `%s` better).  Using `char y[2];` would be possible but dangerous.  Using `"%1s"` with `char y[2];` would be safe.  It is likely to be better to use `char y[4096];` — that leaves space for most inputs (and using `%4095s` would be safe).

Comment: You have to decide whether you want a human language-based ordering (see locale) or a character set or character encoding ordering (either could be termed lexicographic). And also how you want to treat case differences. You probably want to keep it simple, but just realize that's what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up the ASCII table to see how characters are represented in a computer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100] = "";
    int length;
    int i;
    char largest = 'a' - 1; // Init to a value not in ASCII table
    unsigned char smallest = 'z' + 1; // Init to a value not in ASCII table

    scanf("%s", string);
    length = strlen(string);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') {
            if(string[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = string[i];
            }
            if(string[i] > largest) {
                largest = string[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = smallest; i <= largest; i++) {
        printf("%c", i);
    }
    printf("\n");    

    return 0;
}
```

Basically what I'm doing is checking to make sure each char is in the range of 'a' to 'z' because a char in the C language is really an 8 byte integer thus chars can be compared to ints. Then I save the smallest and largest values and loop through them while printing them.

Comment: ok so i changes the numbers to correspond to the askii table and i wrote 'char string[];
 int length;
 int i;
 char largest = 122; // Init to a value not in ASCII table
 char smallest = 97; // Init to a value not in ASCII table
 printf("enter string number ");
 scanf("%d", &length);
 printf("enter the string ");
 scanf("%s", &string);' but it gives me Error reading character of a string

Comment: @Drat018 I edited the solution, copy and paste it and it should work

Comment: @Drat018 note that largest is an unsigned char because a char can only store values up to 127

Comment: @Drat018 also note how I assigned 'a' - 1 to smallest and 'z' + 1 to largest

Comment: thanks it works now but can you tell me why largest is the smaller number and smallest is the largest number should not it be a as the smallest and z the largest .and there is slight problem when for example i enter 7mK#e*gb!c it detects m as smallest first then removes it and does now save it as largest so the computer forgets the m and carries on .so the answer is wrong i tries changing if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') {
   if (string[i] > largest) {
    largest = string[i];
   }
   else if (string[i] > smallest) {
    smallest = string[i];  but it gives me a nothing

Comment: @Drat018 I updated the code to make it work, just turn the else if into another if. I set the smallest to 'z' + 1 because this way any character I read in will be smaller than that value. If I set smallest to 'a' - 1 then the smallest variable will never update because any char between 'a' and 'z' will never be greater than 'a' - 1.  Also, please mark this as the correct answer if you have no more questions.  Thanks, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the smallest and largest letter and how to i make him type the letters in between ?

You should be aware that both your problem statement and your code depend on specifics of the ASCII character set, so it's not a portable result. There's nothing wrong with depending on that, but ASCII is not universal and there is no guarantee that letters are represented consecutively in [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), so there is no easy way to say "the letters in between".  Only the digits `0`-`9` have the guarantee. Per **5.2.1 Character sets**, paragraph 3  of the  C Standard:

> Both  the  basic  source  and  basic  execution  character  sets 
>   shall  have  the  following members: the 26 uppercase letters of the
>   Latin alphabet
>
> ```
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M
> N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> ```
>
> the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>
> ```
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m
> n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> ```
>
> the 10 decimal digits
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```
>
> the following 29 graphic characters
>
> ```
> ! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / :
> ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
> ```
>
> the  space  character, and  control  characters  representing 
>   horizontal  tab,  vertical  tab,  and form  feed.   The 
>   representation  of  each  member  of  the  source  and  execution 
>   basic character sets shall fit in a byte.  **In both the source and
>   execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0`
>   in the above  list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the
>   value of the previous.** ...

[Letters do not have to be represented consecutively.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)  `'a' + 1` does not have to be equal to `'b'`.

The portable way to identify a letter is with the `isalpha()` function:

> **7.4.1.2  The `isalpha` function**
>
> ...
>
> The `isalpha` function tests for any character for which `isupper` or
>   `islower` is true, or  any  character  that  is  one  of  a 
>   locale-specific  set  of  alphabetic  characters  for  which none  of
>   `iscntrl`, `isdigit`, `ispunct`, or `isspace` is  true. In  the `"C"`
>   locale, `isalpha` returns true only for the characters for which
>   `isupper` or `islower` is true.